# Unable to install applications. Help! (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: apt

So I recently installed Ubuntu onto my laptop and have just fallen in love with it. The only problem I'm facing is that whenever I try and install a .deb application (using GDebi package installer,) I get an error status saying "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0)" What does this mean? Is there a way to fix it?

Edit: The version I'm currently using is "ubuntu 16.04"

Comment: What *version* of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: From the settings, it's  "ubuntu 16.04 LTS"

Comment: Have you [enabled the universe repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled it.

Comment: What exactly is the .deb you are trying to install, and why are you using a downloaded .deb file rather than a repository / ppa?

Comment: Initially I tried to install HakuNeko, and that gave me the error that I explained in my original post. But then I got curious, and tried to install another .deb file, which gave me the exact same error. I tried to do it through the console as well as the package installer, but I keep on getting the error. This seems like an issue I shouldn't have, so I really want to find a way to get it fixed. As for your question relating to the repository / ppa, I really have no experience with something like that so I can't give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy fix. When you're trying to install a package it's easiest to do it through Terminal (in my opinion). If you're trying to install, say, myprogram.deb, you would type into terminal `sudo apt-get install myprogram`. Sometimes there are other ways (I would suggest using synaptic package manager if possible). If your package exists and you still have a dependency, type into Terminal `sudo apt-get install myprogram checkinstall`. If you can't find your package, you can install the dependency by hand with `sudo apt-get install dependency-goes-here`, then try installing your package again.

Comment: Okay, so I tried doing what you suggested. I opened terminal and typed in "sudo apt-get install program" (let's assume my .deb file is called program.deb.) When I did that, I got a message stating "E: Unable to locate package program" Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: If it is a .deb, then you'll need to install it through Gdebi or something like you're doing. Instead of installing the rpogram through terminal, try installing the dependencies. If you get a list of dependencies for that, add `checkinstall` at the end of your `sudo apt-get install`.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the missing dependency is the problem.  Your app is looking for `libwxgtk3.0-0` whereas the one installed on Ubuntu 16.04 is `libwxgtk3.0-0v5`.  The version your app is looking for is not available in the repos.

There are two versions of the package [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=libwxgtk3.0-0).  The latest one is the one for **vivid**.  You can download and install it manually using `gdebi` and then you can try installing the app you want.

Before you proceed though, make sure `libwxgtk3.0-0v5` is actually installed.  If not, install that one first and if you face the same problem again, then try the manual installation.

Comment: Alright, so I checked to see if I had libwxgtk3.0-0v5, and lo and behold I actually didn't. So I installed it, and then afterwards tried to install libwxgtk3.0-0. This time it wouldn't install, telling me that the "package is not available, but is referred to by another package...However, the following packages replace it: libwxgtk3.0-0v5:i386 libwxgtk3.0-0v5" That didn't work, so then I tried to install libwxgtk3.0-0 using gdebi, but funnily enough that just prompted another dependency error saying "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libwxbase3.0-0(>=3.0.2)

Comment: I was afraid this would happen.  You are probably trying to install a package that requires older dependencies and until all of them are satisfied this will keep happening.  Are you sure there isn't any newer version of the app you want to install?  In any case, you can find the packages asked for, on www.ubuntuupdates.org the same way and install them manually.